# Layering Multiple Canvases in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, canvas

So I am quite new to WPF and thought that as a learning experience I would implement a simple level editor in WPF. The purpose of the editor is 2-fold. First I want to be able to define arbitrary oriented bounding boxes as the "solid" area in the level. I then want to be able to place, resize, skew images.

[image: polygon editor image]

I have implemented the ability to draw oriented bounding boxes using a Canvas (See image above). The Canvas and a toolbar are within a dock panel. I am now planning to implement the image capabilities. What I thought to do is create another Canvas layer (perhaps many) for each layer of images. The reason for doing so is that I can easily restrict selection and visibility of each layer. However I am not sure how to properly layer multiple canvas controls. Certainly the DockPanel container I am currently using doesn't let me have multiple controls on top of one another. I thought to embed my Canvas layers within another canvas but I am no sure how to properly set this up (note that the setup should be dynamic in code as I would like to allow users to add more layers as necessary).

The ideal end result would be an arbitrary number of layers that have a transparent background (so we can see the layers behind) and which can be easily hidden. There would also only be 1 layer at a time receiving the user input.

So my question is, is their a more appropriate approach rather than layering canvases? If layering of canvases is a good method could someone provide links/example code for how this can be setup. What is the optimal container for multiple stacked controls (note the child canvas size should match the parent container).

Cheers!

Comment: You're definitely on the right track? Why don't you get started and see if you have a more specific question?

Comment: I suppose the question is about whether I am on the right track or not. I have started. I implemented the first portion which allows me to draw the OBBs. Once I reached the next portion I started to wonder whether the approach was correct.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Might I suggest an alternative instead?

- Create an [`ItemsControl`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol.aspx) which utilizes the [`Canvas`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.canvas.aspx) panel as it's drawing surface.
- Bind the [`ItemsControl.ItemsSource`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol.itemssource.aspx) to a collection of custom objects which contain coordinate information.
- Use a [`DataTemplate`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.datatemplate.aspx) to control how each item is visually represented on the canvas. Alternatively, you could use multiple `DataTemplate`s and use a [`DataTemplateSelector`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datatemplateselector.aspx) to choose which one to apply conditionally.

---

**XAML:**

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Path=MyObjectList}">
   <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
      <ItemsPanelTemplate>
         <Canvas />
      </ItemsPanelTemplate>
   </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
   <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
      <DataTemplate>
         <Rectangle Canvas.Left="{Binding Path=X}" Canvas.Top="{Binding Path=Y}"
                    Canvas.ZIndex="{Binding Path=Z}" ... />
      </DataTemplate>
   </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

**C#:**

```
public class MyObject
{
    public double X { get; set; }
    public double Y { get; set; }
    public int Z { get; set; }

    // Additional proeprties...
}
```

This is probably a better alternative than stacking a bunch of canvas panels on top of each other.

---

An excerpt from a [very good resource](http://drwpf.com/blog/2008/02/10/itemscontrol-p-is-for-panel/):

> Let’s just recap a couple of things before we get started… In ‘C’ is
>   for Collection, we learned that an ItemsControl surfaces a collection
>   of items in a very predictable way (namely, as a CollectionView). Then
>   in ‘D’ is for DataTemplate, we learned that an item within the
>   collection can be any CLR object and the visual representation of the
>   item is defined using a template of visual elements (called a
>   DataTemplate).
>
> The next question that logically arises is, “where do we put these
>   visuals?” More specifically, once the data template for an item has
>   been inflated, where should its visuals be positioned? To answer this
>   question, we will now examine how “layout” is handled for items within
>   an ItemsControl.

Basically:

- ItemsControl - Collection of items
- DataTemplate - How each item is visually represented
- Panel - How each visual representation is laid out.

Comment: +1, though the OP stated he needs different "layers" specifically

Comment: @HighCore: He also asked if there is a "*more appropriate approach rather than layering canvases*" ...

Comment: I'll have to look into this because its all new to me! But seems like a good WPF approach. Thanks.

Comment: Hi, I have question related to your method. So I have played around with this approach and I really like the strong separation of data and visuals that it provides. But as HighCore mentioned it doesn't seem to help with the issue of layering. Is there a good approach (without actually layering multiple ItemsControls) that lets me hide/disable a large subset of the items. For example am I able to bind multiple collections to the same ItemsCollection? If not is layering of multiple ItemsCollections possible?

Comment: @DeusAduro: To address the issue of visibility of an object there are a couple of ways you could do this. The first way is to simply remove the object from the ItemsSource (the collection) to hide, add it back to show it again. Alternatively, you could have some sort of bool value to indicate visibility, and use the `BooleanToVisibility` converter on the `Visibility` property in XAML to show/hide the visual item. As far as multiple types in an ItemsCollection, you could always set your collection to store to their most common base (`System.Object`) and use the `DataTemplateSelector` mentioned.

Comment: Makes sense. I'll give that a try, so no strong sense of layers but I can make it work for sure. Thanks. I'll mark this as correct.

Comment: Sorry if this sounds like a silly question, but can you please explain why using an external items control is better than just using the Canvas.Children collection?

Comment: @Ben: That's a different question altogether, if you ask that question, I can answer it separately.